# Procedure or function (stored procedure name) has too many arguments specified

Tags: sql-server, vb.net, stored-procedures

I know this problem has been answered but I already tried some of the solution on those but I still can't solved mine.

Procedure Code

```
USE [PROPERTY_MANAGEMENT_FOPMLIVE]
GO

SET ANSI_NULLS ON
GO
SET QUOTED_IDENTIFIER ON
GO

ALTER PROCEDURE [dbo].[create_budget1000] 
    -- Add the parameters for the stored procedure here
        @id varchar(36),
        @parentid varchar(36),
        @item nvarchar(47),
        @dsca nvarchar(255),
        @category nvarchar(255),
        @pid varchar(50),
        @companyid varchar(50),
        @subl int,
        --@amnt float,
        --@consumed float,
        --@balance float,
        @budget_type varchar(50),
        @fiscal_year int,
        @budget_description text,
        @active int,
        @budget_policy varchar(50),
        @budget_code nvarchar(36),
        @date_created datetime,
        @created_by varchar(36),
        @budget_for varchar(50),
        @gl_code varchar(50)
AS
BEGIN
    -- SET NOCOUNT ON added to prevent extra result sets from
    -- interfering with SELECT statements.
    SET NOCOUNT ON;

    -- Insert statements for procedure here
    INSERT INTO [dbo].[Budgets1000]
           ([id]
           ,[parentid]
           ,[item]
           ,[dsca]
           ,[category]
           ,[pid]
           ,[companyid]
           ,[subl]
           ,[amnt]
           ,[consumed]
           ,[balance]
           ,[budget_type]
           ,[fiscal_year]
           ,[budget_description]
           ,[active]
           ,[budget_policy]
           ,[budget_code]
           ,[date_created]
           ,[created_by]
           ,[budget_for]
           ,[gl_code])
     VALUES
           (@id
           ,@parentid
           ,@item
           ,@dsca
           ,@category
           ,@pid
           ,@companyid
           ,@subl
           ,0
           ,0
           ,0
           ,@budget_type
           ,@fiscal_year
           ,@budget_description
           ,@active
           ,@budget_policy
           ,@budget_code
           ,@date_created
           ,@created_by
           ,@budget_for
           ,@gl_code)
END
```

VB.Net Code

```
Public Sub createItem()
    Dim objConStr As ConnectionStringSettings = ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings("TII")
    Dim Con As New SqlConnection(objConStr.ConnectionString)

    Dim IPAddress As String = Request.UserHostAddress
    Dim cmdsql2 As New SqlCommand
    cmdsql2.Connection = Con
    cmdsql2.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure
    cmdsql2.CommandText = cs_properties.generate_replace_dbo_byproperty_id("[dbo].[create_budget]", Session("company_id"))

    Dim budgetID As String = Guid.NewGuid.ToString
    budgetID_hold = budgetID

    cmdsql2.Parameters.Add("@id", SqlDbType.VarChar)
    cmdsql2.Parameters("@id").Value = budgetID

    cmdsql2.Parameters.Add("@parentid", SqlDbType.VarChar)
    cmdsql2.Parameters("@parentid").Value = ddl_parent.SelectedValue

    If ddl_level.SelectedValue = "9" Then
        cmdsql2.Parameters.Add("@item", SqlDbType.NVarChar)
        cmdsql2.Parameters("@item").Value = "-"

        cmdsql2.Parameters.Add("@dsca", SqlDbType.NVarChar)
        cmdsql2.Parameters("@dsca").Value = txt_name.Text
    Else
        If ddl_budgetFor.SelectedValue = "Finance" Then
            cmdsql2.Parameters.Add("@item", SqlDbType.NVarChar)
            cmdsql2.Parameters("@item").Value = "-"

            cmdsql2.Parameters.Add("@dsca", SqlDbType.NVarChar)
            cmdsql2.Parameters("@dsca").Value = ddl_gl.SelectedValue

            cmdsql2.Parameters.Add("@category", SqlDbType.NVarChar)
            cmdsql2.Parameters("@category").Value = "-"
        Else
            If Session("company_id") = "1000" Then
                cmdsql2.Parameters.Add("@category", SqlDbType.NVarChar)
                cmdsql2.Parameters("@category").Value = "-"
            Else
                cmdsql2.Parameters.Add("@category", SqlDbType.NVarChar)
                cmdsql2.Parameters("@category").Value = ddl_category.SelectedValue
            End If

            cmdsql2.Parameters.Add("@item", SqlDbType.NVarChar)
            cmdsql2.Parameters("@item").Value = ddl_item.SelectedValue

            cmdsql2.Parameters.Add("@dsca", SqlDbType.NVarChar)
            cmdsql2.Parameters("@dsca").Value = ddl_item.SelectedItem.Text

        End If

    End If

    'cmdsql2.Parameters.Add("@category", SqlDbType.NVarChar)
    'cmdsql2.Parameters("@category").Value = ddl_category.SelectedValue

    cmdsql2.Parameters.Add("@pid", SqlDbType.VarChar)
    cmdsql2.Parameters("@pid").Value = "1"

    cmdsql2.Parameters.Add("@companyid", SqlDbType.VarChar)
    cmdsql2.Parameters("@companyid").Value = Session("company_id")

    cmdsql2.Parameters.Add("@subl", SqlDbType.Int)
    cmdsql2.Parameters("@subl").Value = ddl_level.SelectedValue

    cmdsql2.Parameters.Add("@budget_type", SqlDbType.VarChar)
    cmdsql2.Parameters("@budget_type").Value = Request.QueryString("budgettype")

    cmdsql2.Parameters.Add("@fiscal_year", SqlDbType.Int)
    cmdsql2.Parameters("@fiscal_year").Value = Request.QueryString("fiscalyear")

    cmdsql2.Parameters.Add("@budget_description", SqlDbType.Text)
    cmdsql2.Parameters("@budget_description").Value = ""

    cmdsql2.Parameters.Add("@active", SqlDbType.Int)
    cmdsql2.Parameters("@active").Value = 1

    cmdsql2.Parameters.Add("@budget_policy", SqlDbType.VarChar)
    cmdsql2.Parameters("@budget_policy").Value = Request.QueryString("budgetpolicy")

    cmdsql2.Parameters.Add("@budget_code", SqlDbType.NVarChar)
    cmdsql2.Parameters("@budget_code").Value = Request.QueryString("budgetcode")

    cmdsql2.Parameters.Add("@date_created", SqlDbType.DateTime)
    cmdsql2.Parameters("@date_created").Value = System.DateTime.Now

    cmdsql2.Parameters.Add("@created_by", SqlDbType.VarChar)
    cmdsql2.Parameters("@created_by").Value = Session("userid")

    If ddl_level.SelectedValue = "9" Then
        cmdsql2.Parameters.Add("@budget_for", SqlDbType.VarChar)
        cmdsql2.Parameters("@budget_for").Value = "-"
    Else
        cmdsql2.Parameters.Add("@budget_for", SqlDbType.VarChar)
        cmdsql2.Parameters("@budget_for").Value = ddl_budgetFor.SelectedItem.Text
    End If

    If ddl_budgetFor.SelectedItem.Text = "Finance" Then
        cmdsql2.Parameters.Add("@gl_code", SqlDbType.VarChar)
        cmdsql2.Parameters("@gl_code").Value = ddl_gl.SelectedValue

        'cmdsql2.Parameters.Add("@amnt", SqlDbType.VarChar)
        'cmdsql2.Parameters("@amnt").Value = finance_amount.Text

        cmdsql2.Parameters.Add("@category", SqlDbType.NVarChar)
        cmdsql2.Parameters("@category").Value = "-"
    Else
        cmdsql2.Parameters.Add("@gl_code", SqlDbType.VarChar)
        cmdsql2.Parameters("@gl_code").Value = "-"

        'cmdsql2.Parameters.Add("@amnt", SqlDbType.Float)
        'cmdsql2.Parameters("@amnt").Value = 0

        cmdsql2.Parameters.Add("@category", SqlDbType.NVarChar)
        cmdsql2.Parameters("@category").Value = ddl_category.SelectedValue

    End If

    'cmdsql2.Parameters.Add("@consumed", SqlDbType.Float)
    'cmdsql2.Parameters("@consumed").Value = 0

    'cmdsql2.Parameters.Add("@balance", SqlDbType.Float)
    'cmdsql2.Parameters("@balance").Value = 0

    If Con.State = ConnectionState.Closed Then Con.Open()
    Try
        cmdsql2.ExecuteNonQuery()
    Catch ex As Exception
        Response.Write("<script>alert('" & ex.Message & "');</script>")
    Finally
        If Con.State = ConnectionState.Open Then Con.Close()
        Con.Close()
    End Try

    SqlConnection.ClearPool(Con)
End Sub
```

---

I already checked if my parameters are filled in correctly in my code and it looks okay to me but when I'm running it, it always gives me an error.

Comment: It looks like you may be adding the @category parameter more than once.

Comment: This code is a real mess, I suggest you refactor it and the error will almost certainly go away.

Comment: @MikeS It may look like I'm adding it multiple times but the category parameter outside my If Else statement is already commented out. Sorry I forgot to remove that.

Comment: No, you are adding `@category` again near the bottom

Comment: When using (N)varchar you need to specify the scale or you will get the default. Do you know what the default is? Do you know that is can change depending on if is a variable or a parameter? Cleaning this code up would go a long way to long term maintenance.

Comment: @DavidG It's actually the code of my workmate that resigned. They just assigned me to modify it, i already suggested starting that class from scratch but they forbid me from doing it so I'm trying my best to actually make this one workout.

Comment: @JericCabuyaban Then tell your colleague to come here so we can convince him that this code is very poor and needs to be rewritten!

Comment: @DavidG Thanks for the help. It's actually the category parameter that messes the code. I'll consider refactoring it once the this project goes live and just needs minor revisions. This is why I really hate continuing codes that are half assed done and I did not started.

Comment: Some advice from someone who's been working in the industry along time. If you firmly believe refactoring some code (especially such a small section of code) will make it more maintainable or faster, it might be worth just doing and not asking permission ahead of time. Sometimes it is better to apologize after the fact (especially if your refactor works) then to ask permission first.

Comment: @MikeS I will take note of that advice from you. The thing is I was hired in this company to continue this module of the system we're working on, I am confident that I can finish this one easily considering the fact that I am using C# in my previous company but I am not that new in using VB. And they did not say that this module was like 30% done and this project is in critical period because they need this module this coming Friday. Anyways I still need to learn a lot in this industry because I'm still a newbie. Thanks again for the advice.

Comment: Before this line     'cmdsql2.Parameters.Add("@consumed", SqlDbType.Float)
    'cmdsql2.Parameters("@consumed").Value = 0

    'cmdsql2.Parameters.Add("@balance", SqlDbType.Float)
    'cmdsql2.Parameters("@balance").Value = 0
you added category again